# Safe to store user id and role id in localstorage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I got conflicting answers wherein few people stated that localstorage is ok to use and few vehemently stating not to use localstorage for storing user id, role id, JWT token. I got overwhelmed with lot of answers and suggestions, and so decided to post a question to get clarity.

I have a microservice application with react js front and flask backend with JWT token. Post login, I grab the user ID, role ID, JWT token coming from backend and have it stored in localstorage in react js. I use role ID to display menus/links particular to that role.

My question is, Is it safe to store user ID and role ID in localstorage? Would it be even more safer if i were to use libraries like react-secure-storage to safely store in localstorage? If not, then what is the best way to store user id, role id and JWT token?

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on how "sensitive" the data you are looking to store is.  The reason it isn't a good idea to store data in localStorage is because of how insecure localStorage is.  If someone uses your app from a computer at a library, then someone else sits at the same computer....that second person could have the ability to read the data in the localStorage from the first user.

So you have to ask yourself: how "sensitive" is the data that you are persisting?  If someone else got that data, what (damage) could they do with it?

This is true of any data persistence, not just localStorage.  Same goes for Cookies, or even data that you store "securely".  You need to understand that data stored on disk can be recovered by someone with enough skill, tools and/or time.  "Encrypting data" just makes the amount of skill and/or time needed to recover that data increase a bit.